# Branch-coverage with Cobertura plugin for the Play! Framework

Tags: unit-testing, branch, playframework, cobertura

I'm using the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) with the [Cobertura module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/cobertura) to get code coverage. This works fine, but unfortunately, the module seems to have no (obvious) option to make branch coverage reports too.
How do I enable branch coverage in the Cobertura module?
Or in other words, how do you test branch coverage in a Play application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branch coverage magically appears in the report now, maybe it was there all the time and I just didn't see it. My bad.